# How can i connect a SIP server with swift

Tags: ios, swift, sip

We have a SIP server, how can i connect this server with swift.And how can i data transfer in this server. Is there any library in swift for do this. I couldnt find any resource. Help me please.

Comment: you can use PJSIP.

Comment: i am trying. I have not built pjsip yet. Is there other ways you already know.

Comment: @Himanshu I have been searching the way of doing this over some time now. Only option does seem like `pjsip`. However there is no documentation how to use it in `swift`. where should I do?